# Filter nested schema rows in query result - Sqlalchemy (Marshmallow)

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

Consider the following: A set of `Accounts` that have a `Status` that can be `ACTIVE` or `DELETED`. A set of `Entries` for each `Account` that also have a status `ACTIVE/DELETED`.

Here is an example of the data object for 2 accounts:

```js
accounts = [{
  "account_id": 1,
  "status": {
    "status_id": 1,
    "status_name": "active"
  },
  "account_entries": [{
    "entry_id": 1,
    "status": {
      "status_id": 1,
      "status_name": "active"
    }
  }, {
    "entry_id": 2,
    "status": {
      "status_id": 2,
      "status_name": "deleted"
    }
  }]
}, {
  "account_id": 2,
  "status": {
    "status_id": 2,
    "status_name": "deleted"
  },
  "account_entries": [{
    "entry_id": 1,
    "status": {
      "status_id": 1,
      "status_name": "active"
    }
  }]
}]
```

To simplify the above:

```py
accounts:
  1: active
  entries:
    1: active,
    2: deleted
  2: deleted
  entries:
    1: active
```

Would like to query accounts and their entries, filtered by `active` status - to return an object that does not include any `deleted` accounts or entries.

```py
accounts:
  1: active
  entries:
    1: active
```

To filter the active accounts, currently using:

```py
# query all active accounts
all_accounts = Account.query.filter(Account.status_id == "1")
```

**Is it possible to extend the query to apply the filter to the entries as well?**

Here are the schemas for: account, entry, status - in `models.py`

```py
class Account(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'account'

    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    status_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('status.id'))
    status = db.relationship('Status', backref='accounts')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Account {}>'.format(self.id)
```

```py
class Entry(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'entry'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    status_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('status.id'), nullable=False)
    status = db.relationship('Status', backref='entries')

    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('account.id'), nullable=False)
    account = db.relationship('Account', foreign_keys=[account_id], backref=db.backref('account_entries'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Entry {}>'.format(self.id)
```

```py
class Status(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'status'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Status {}>'.format(self.id)
```

And those are the schemas setup in `views.py`:

```py
class StatusSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Status


class EntrySchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    status = ma.Nested(StatusSchema)
    account = ma.Nested(lambda: AccountSchema(only=("id", "name")))

    class Meta:
        model = Entry


class AccountSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    account_entries = ma.List(ma.Nested(EntrySchema(exclude=("account",))))
    status = ma.Nested(StatusSchema)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by following V. Chikunov answer's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58236761)

The thing that worked for me was adding the `contains_eager()` to my query; without it I was getting all the rows in my nested schema like it was ignoring the filter statment.

In your case, I think your query should be:

```
all_accounts = Account.query.join(Status) \
                      .filter(Status.name == "active") \
                      .options(contains_eager(Status.name)) \
                      .all()
```